# How to make select box fit parent div height in a table row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the **Type filter** select box fit the row height. So far I have tried adding `style="height: 100%;"` in both the select and parent div tag but nothing changed.

Follows phtml code and page image.

```html
<td>
  <div>
    <select id="type_filter" name="type_filter" class="form-select">
      <option></option>
      <?php foreach ( $session_types as $type ): ?>
        <option value="<?=$type["type"]?>"><?=$type["typename"]?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container div will need a height, otherwise it will shrink to the height of the select element.

```css
select {
    height: 100%;
}
.test {
    height: 40px;
    border-style: solid
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=content-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>test</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

<td>
  <div class="test">
    <select id="type_filter" name="type_filter" class="form-select">
      <option></option>
      <?php foreach ( $session_types as $type ): ?>
        <option value="<?=$type["type"]?>"><?=$type["typename"]?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</td> 

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this did not work. Has a similar effect of adding  height: 100%; as I did before. The element does not change it's height.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the code.